# Adding an element during enumeration

Tags: c#, .net

When the first condition doesn't satisfy because product is not already in the collection, it's then added via the else statement. However, when it is added - the foreach loop continues until all objects have been iterated - yet it never enters p._id == product._id and will continue to the else statement, adding another identical object.

May this be because I'm adding an element to a collection during enumeration? It's not actually added until enumeration is completed.

```
public void AddProduct(Product product)
{
    foreach(Product p in products)
    {
        if(p._id == product._id)
        {
            product._qty = product._qty + p._qty;
        }
        else
        {
            inventory.Add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `break;` after you add the product

Comment: Als oI would advice you to use some **Dictionary** or **HashSet**

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius He's enumerating the `products` collection, but adding to the `inventory` collection, which will be fine (I made the same assumption at first as well!)

Comment: @RB. Oh, yeah right, didn't notice that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Why not just use Linq for this?

Comment: Side note - I would recommend using a dictionary instead of a list for your backing store, assuming `_id` is an int, then `IDictionary<int, Product> products;`, then use dictionary's built in `ContainsKey()`, `Add()`, etc. methods.

Comment: @maccettura Do you mean creating side effects `product._qty = product._qty + p._qty;`  while enumerating on products?

Comment: @L.B now that I think about it, my way would be doubley enumerating the set.  I imagined a FirstOrDefault match on the ID, and an Except to add the differences to inventory

Comment: Following your original intent: modifying the underlying collection of an enumeration is not a goo idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use While loop or for loop , it does not throw CollectionChangedException .

Comment: Your explanation would be better if you provided a code example and why